# Value for object in a another Class is not set in a Class

Tags: objective-c, set

In a class, i want set value for a label from a another view.

The first class to assign value:

```
#import "ViewDetailPoinmap.h"
...

NSLog(@"On a cliqué sur : %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]);
//On a cliqué sur : 2130

ViewDetailPoinmap *detailPoint = [[ViewDetailPoinmap alloc] init];
detailPoint.idPoint =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
detailPoint.txtIDPoint.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]];
```

The another class (ViewDetailPoinmap.h):

```
@interface ViewDetailPoinmap : UIViewController{
NSNumber *idPoint;
IBOutlet UILabel *txtIDPoint;
}
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *txtIDPoint;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *idPoint;
@end
```

(ViewDetailPoinmap.m)

```
...
@synthesize txtIDPoint;
@synthesize idPoint;


...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"ON arrive sur la page détail du point : %@",idPoint);
    //ON arrive sur la page détail du point : (null)

}
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You marked property as `assign` and it refers to variable in first class. Probably that variable is already autoreleased.

```
detailPoint.idPoint =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]; // here you assign
```

Try to change here `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *idPoint;` assign to **retain**

Comment: Don't forget to release it (if ARC isn't enabled) in dealloc!

Comment: there is already [detailPoint release]; in method to assign value

Comment: I mean release for _retained_ property

Comment: @AlexandreOuicher, did you _Try to change here `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *idPoint;` assign to retain_?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8021/discussion-between-alexandre-ouicher-and-beryllium)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create the `txtIDPoint` instance? You've shown where you try to set its text, but unless you've initialised the label itself that will be `nil` which is consistent with the symptoms you describe.

Comment: It's not a problem with text. NSlog return (null) => NSLog(@"ON arrive sur la page détail du point : %@",idPoint);

Comment: i don't understand. Where would you that i create a instance in the first class